Simplified Proof of that Ampleness can be checked after Faithfully Flat Base Change
Let $f:X \to S$ be a morphism of schemes and $L$ an invertible sheaf on $X$. It is well known that relative amplessness of $L$ can be checked on fpcq base change, ie if $g: S' \to S$ is fpqc, then $L$ is ample iff $g'^*L$ is flat on $X_{S'}:= X \times _{S'} S$ where $g': X_{S'} \to X$ is pullback of $g$ along $f$.
See eg Stacks, OD2P and compare with this question.
The proof works in rather general setting, but I'm wondering if in special case $S:=\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ and $S':=\operatorname{Spec}(K)$  with $K$ finite (so algebraic) field extension of base field $k$ of $X$, the proof can be strongly simplified roughly in following vein:
A well known criterion for (absolute) ampleness of $L$ is that it is ample iff for every coherent sheaf $F$ and every (closed) point $x \in X$ - let use here assume that every closed subscheme of $X$ contains closed points -there exist a $n_0=n_0(F)$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$ the canonical map
$$  \Gamma(X, F \otimes L^n) \to \Gamma(X, F \otimes k(x)) $$
($k(x)$ is skyscraper sheaf at $x$) is surjective.
Now this suggests that this can be turned into strong simplification of the proof that "$g'^*L$ ample implies $L$ ample" up to a little detail I don't know how to overcome. So let assume $g'^*L$ ample.
By faithfully flatness to show that $  \Gamma(X, F \otimes L^n) \to \Gamma(X, F \otimes k(x)) $ is surjective, it suffice to check it after tensoring by $K$ (as both are $k$- modules and $k \to K$ clearly faithfully flat.
Now by general flat base change results(see eg Hartshorne flatness chapter) we have for arbitrary quasicoh. sheaf $G$ on $X$ the canonical identification
$$  \Gamma(X,G) \otimes_k K \cong \Gamma(X_K, g'^*G) $$
So the surjectivity of above map on $X$ reduces to surjectivity (after tensoring it with $K$ and using the mentioned canon identification) to surjectivity of
$$  \Gamma(X_K, g'^*F \otimes (g'^*L)^n) \to \Gamma(X, (g'^*F) \otimes k(x) \otimes K) = \oplus_{x' \in g'^{-1}(x)} \Gamma(X_K, (g'^*F) \otimes k(x') ) $$
Now, if we assume $g'^*L$ to be ample, then for every preimage $x' \in g'^{-1}(x)$ the canonical cap
$$  \Gamma(X_K, g'^*F \otimes (g'^*L)^n) \to \Gamma(X_K, (g'^*F) \otimes k(x') ) $$
is surjetive, but does it suffice $  \Gamma(X_K, g'^*F \otimes (g'^*L)^n) \to  \oplus_{x' \in g'^{-1}(x)} \Gamma(X_K, (g'^*F) \otimes k(x') ) $ to be also ample?
In general, if $f_i: N \to M_i$ are surjective $R$-module maps, induced $N \to \oplus_i M_i $ not need to be surjective. So this cannot follow from abstract nonsense argument.
So the key question is, if $g'^*L$ is ample, $G$ coherent sheaf and $n$ big enough does for any finite sets of closed points $x_1,..., x_d \in X_K$ exist a global section $s \in \Gamma(X_K, G \otimes (g'^*L)^n) $ with $ s(x_1) \neq 0$ and $s(x_i)=0$ for $i\neq 1$?
Clearly, this would be equivalent to surjectivity of the map above and so the question is does this hold for ample $g'^*L$. So the purpose of the question is if the suggested way to simplify the proof that ampleness can be checked after faithfully flat base change in case base scheme be a field can be turn in actually in a flawless argument.

Think here an almost full argument how to resolve it: If we know that $g'^*L$ is ample, then we know (one of many equiv cretaria) that open subsets $X_f,$ where $ f \in \Gamma(X_K, (g'^*L)^n), n \ge 1$ (...openness of $X_f$ can be easily checked on an affine covering trivializing $g'^*L$...) form basis of topology of $X$.
Then there exist always a canonical map
$$ \Gamma(X_K,  (g'^*L)^n) \otimes_K    \Gamma(X_K, g'^*F \otimes (g'^*L)^n) \to   \Gamma(X_K, g'^*F \otimes (g'^*L)^{n+m})  $$
If $x_1,..., x_d \in X_K$, by surjectivity of $  \Gamma(X_K, g'^*F \otimes (g'^*L)^m) \to \Gamma(X_K, (g'^*F) \otimes k(x_1) ) $ we can find a seection $s$ with $s(x_1) \neq 0$ and a $t \in \Gamma(X_K,  (g'^*L)^n)  $ with $x_1 \in X_t $ and $x_i \not \in X_t$ for $i \neq 1$. Then $ts$ does the job for key question.
The problem is - that's why I called it an "almost solution" - that $n$ depends on $x' \in X_K$. Can we find a $n_0$ such that already $X_f$ for $f \in \Gamma(X_K,  (g'^*L)^n)  $ with $n \le n_0$ form a basis for topology of $X_K$ under ampleness assumption for $g'^*L$? That would fill the last gap.
